# suggestions for json

Tags: jquery, json

Is the correct usage? Which one you need to use. Below I share the sample codes. I need a recommendation for.

```
 {
    "__bc"  : 1,
    "_payload" : null,
    "_plugin" : [.........],
    "_debug" : "on",
    "_content" : [
                          "html":{<form name=\"signin\" id=\"signin\" action=\"javascript:;\" onsubmit=\"return false\"><label id=\"username\">username:</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id="\username\"/></form>}
                      ]
   }
```

or standart html;

```
<form name="signin" id="signin" action="javascript:;" onsubmit="return false">
    <label id="username">username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Yes the top sample is JSON, but what are you asking?  It looks like the html is in your JSON, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @drneel i think he's asking if that's the right way to transmit the html snippet with json. and no, the sample is not valid json

Comment: I put the html code into json. Is a true work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JSON. You want to keep the markup separate. jQuery has a function `.data(key,value)` for storing values in the DOM.

For example:

```
$('form').data(formdata, {name: "signin", id: "signin"});
```

This stores a JSON in the form element. It is retrieved by specifying the key:

$('form').data(form data); //returns {name: "signin", id: "signing"}

You should get the general idea from this example. The [documentation for `.data(key,value)` is here.](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need to retrieve the html code you can, but you could just select it from the markup using `$(form).html()`. Unless there is some performance issue that requires you to store it as a string. What exactly do you want to do with the html your storing?

Answer (score 0):

[**here**](http://jsonlint.com/) you can validate your json.
Your's is not valid.

This should be valid:

```
{
    "__bc": 1,
    "_payload": null,
    "_plugin": [],
    "_debug": "on",
    "_content": {
        "html": "<formname=\"signin\"id=\"signin\"action=\"javascript: ;\"onsubmit=\"returnfalse\"><labelid=\"username\">username: </label><inputtype=\"text\"name=\"username\"id=\"username\"/></form>"
    }
}
```